# Apps Script set ActiveUser and timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script

Please help with setting active user in Column N.  This script will timestamp column M whenever a cell in a row is updated. However, nothing updates in Column N for the active user.

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Log" ) { //checks that we're on the correct 
 sheet

 var r = s.getActiveCell();
 var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

 if( r.getColumn() != 13 ) { //checks the column
 var row = r.getRow();
 var time = new Date();
 time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-07:00", "yyyy-MM-dd, hh:mm:ss");
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('M' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("N" + row.toString()).setValue(user);
     }
   };
 };
```

Am I using setValue(user) incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to setValue() looks fine.  You may be encountering an authorization issue.

Can you successfully run this same code outside of the onEdit() trigger?

There are restrictions on the actions that can be performed inside of an onEdit trigger.  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Comment: Thanks that was exactly it. I had to republish for the new permissions to allow it.